# Distance between quotation mark and text

Tags: csquotes

I'm using `\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}` with `\textquote{...}` and `\enquote{...}` for quoting but, it seems to me that the left quotation mark is too close to the text, especially when it begins with "t".

Is it correct?

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

Some text \textquote{text of quotation}.

Some other text \enquote{text of quotation}.

Some text \textquote{other text of quotation}.

Some other text \enquote{other text of quotation}.

Some other text ``text of quotation''.

Some other text ``other text of quotation''.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a ligature correction `\/` is an option: `\textquotes{\/text of quotation}`?

Comment: Thank you, @ChristianHupfer, Schweinebacke suggest to me a solution with `lmodern`, I think I'll use that if it has no contraindication.

Comment: No problem for me ... it was a suggestion only, not a eloborate answer like Schweinebacke provided

Comment: You should also add the example with the explicit quotes, for better comparison.

Comment: @egreg I'll do it ASAP (I'm at work now and I can't).

Comment: @CarLaTeX I did that for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The distance between the quote and the following letter depends on the kerning information of the font. This is a decision (or missing decision) of the font designer. `csquotes` also provides a fallback setting, if the font does not have a corresponding kerning pair. The fallback can be set by the optional argument of between the closing outer mark and the opening inner mark of `\DeclareQuoteStyle`. The default definition of (the American variant of) style `english` at `csquotes.def` is

```
\DeclareQuoteStyle[american]{english}% verified
  {\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}
```

Changing the `0.05em` does not change anything in your example. So it seems, that for European Computer Modern (the font you are using because of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` the optional fallback kerning is not used.

Nevertheless you could force another kerning after `\textquotedblleft` using the `\kern` primitive:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=70pt}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[american]{english}% verified
  {\textquotedblleft\kern0.01em}% force additional kerning
  {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]% Fallback only for fonts without kerning
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}

\begin{document}
    \raggedright
    Some text \textquote{text of quotation}.\\ Some other text \enquote{text of quotation}.\\ Some text \textquote{other text of quotation}.\\ Some other text \enquote{other text of quotation}.
\end{document}
```

[image: extra kerning]

But note: This would add extra kerning independent of the font and independent of the letter that follows the double quote!

An alternative would be to use a font with improved kerning, e.g., Latin Modern:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=70pt}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    \raggedright
    Some text \textquote{text of quotation}.\\ Some other text \enquote{text of quotation}.\\ Some text \textquote{other text of quotation}.\\ Some other text \enquote{other text of quotation}.
\end{document}
```

[image: LM instead of EC]

Comment: Thank you, I'll use the solution with `lmodern`.